# Biblatex: No \postnotedelim for citations that aren't numerals

Tags: biblatex, citing, conditionals

When I am citing pages in books, I use the citation format

> (Author 1982:45)

But when I am citing something like paragraphs or online data with an ID number (i.e. things that aren't a plain numeral like a page number), I would like to remove the colon:

> (Online resource no. 58; Author 1975 §18)

I assume the necessary trick here is to specify an empty `\postnotedelim` iff the postnote is not a numeral. How can I accomplish this (adding something to the preamble in my `.tex` file)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{harrison,
    AUTHOR = "George Harrison",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1982",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Big House"}
@ONLINE{archiveZ,
    TITLE = "Archive Z",
    SHORTHAND = "Archive Z",
    URL = "http://www.archivez.com",
    URLDATE = "2013-03-22"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencites[45]{harrison}[no. 58]{archiveZ}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved by the following code

```
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{%
  \iffieldnums{postnote}
    {\addcolon}
    {\addspace}}
```

Comment: The package ``xtring`` isn't included in ``TeXLive``, even though I have installed ``TeXLive`` with _all_ packages. How is ``\IfInteger`` different from ``\ifnumerals``?

Comment: @Sverre I have changed the answer. The package would have been `xstring`. `\IfInteger` is from `xstring`, `\ifnumerals` is from `biblatex`. `\ifnumerals` or `\iffieldnums` would consider numbers also in different forms (roman and ranges).

Comment: `biblatex` now also has `\iffieldpages` which is probably most appropriate here.