# What kind of citation style is it?

Tags: biblatex, citing, back-referencing

I am writing my doctoral thesis, but I am frustrated when I try to output the reference format as my school required, it's required as follow (Only the following three types are needed in my thesis),

**Journal [J]**

[image]

**Book [M]**

[image]

**Conference [C]**
[image]

Other requirements:

1. Multiple authors: when the number of authors are greater than 3, keep first three and use "et al" for the rest authors.
2. Sorting: By appearance.

My question is what kind of the bibliography style the above is?

and if there is none of the existing bibliography styles fitting for it, how should I build this style from scratch?

`.bib`:

```
@article{brauner91,
  author = {Brauner, N.},
  title = {Vapour absorption into falling film},
  journal = {ASME J},
  year = {1991},
  volume = {34},
  pages = {76-82},
  number = {3}
}
@book{baehr1994,
  title={Heat and mass transfer},
  author={Baehr, H. D.},
  year={1994},
  page={221}
  publisher={Berlin:Springer-Verlag}
}
@inproceedings{leiner1989,
  year  = {1989},
  pages={68--71},
  author = {Leiner, A.},
  title = {Optical techniques for heat transfer measurements},
  booktitle = { COLLINS W. Proc Int Conf on Energy and Environment},
  publisher={New York: Academic Press}
}
```

Comment: Is there a number in front of the entry? or is this really all there is?

Comment: Yes, it has. I omitted here for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Is there any explanation as to why there is a "[J]" after the title? The rest looks fairly standard. You have to play around with the name format a bit and some care will be needed for the journal and number. Please be aware though that this is not nearly enough to properly write a style for your thesis. What about `@book`s, `@incollection`s etc. Normally it is preferred to ask only one specific question per question here. How do I write a style for this can easy become a very broad issue.

Comment: That *omitting for the sake of simplicity* is actually **hiding useful information**. So you want to use a simple `numeric` citation/bibliography style.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your reply, I have updated my questions based on your answer, plz have a look.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your reminder. Yes, I want a `numeric` citation.

Comment: That is unfortunately still not enough information to properly write up a style. What if you have two or more authors? How is the list sorted? ...

Comment: There was a similar questiion not long ago, [and my response](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=93918#p93918).

Comment: @moewe Updated, 1) Two more authors: greater than 3 authors, use "et al" for the rest authors. 2) Sorting: Numeric

Comment: What sorting is "numeric"? By appearance? And I don't understand what you are saying with the names. If I have more than three authors, do I give one and et al the others or do I give up to two?

Comment: @moewe Yes, like the IEEE style.

Comment: @moewe I just mistaken your reply, regarding the author names, if authors are 4, keep first 3, and replace the rest as 'et al'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,giveninits=true,sorting=none,maxnames=3,minnames=3]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \ifentrytype{article}{\setunit{}\printtext{[A]}}{}
     \ifentrytype{book}{\setunit{}\printtext{[B]}}{}%
     \ifentrytype{inproceedings}{\setunit{}\printtext{[C]}}{}
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{//}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{%
  \iffieldpages{postnote}
    {\addcolon\space}
    {\addspace}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,brauner91,baehr1994,leiner1989,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Most of this is fairly standard and can be found in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), [biblatex: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17583/35864), [Colon instead of “p.” in Biblatex authoryear-comp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66394/35864), [Biblatex: No \postnotedelim for citations that aren't numerals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103770/35864), [biblatex: parentheses around the volume number of an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81569/35864)

The odd requirements of your style were the indication of the entry type after the title as we as the "//" separator for "in", they are implemented via

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \ifentrytype{article}{\setunit{}\printtext{[A]}}{}
     \ifentrytype{book}{\setunit{}\printtext{[B]}}{}%
     \ifentrytype{inproceedings}{\setunit{}\printtext{[C]}}{}
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{//}}}
```

the latter of course follows the general pattern of [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).

Comment: @moewe Do you see any use in collecting the custoizations of every question on github? It sometimes feels like a good idea, but then ... it is not a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: @Johannes_B That pretty much describes my feelings about it `;-)` If it were on github people might expect proper styles that are ready to use. Sometimes when I write answers though the code that comes out could be streamlined and improved quite a bit. Often questions only focus on particular aspects of one style (see here) so that I would feel uncomfortable releasing this into the wild with much of `biblatex`'s behaviour not checked for compliance. Plus it might make people think that the github repository provides support for those styles and that opens up another can of worms

Comment: *Can of worms* That matches. By the way, i asked the *Bibliotheksdirektorin* about ISO 690 and DIN 1505. She admitted not to have a deeper knowledge, but asked: "Is das nich nur ganz allgemein gehalten? Da steht doch nichts spezifisches drin, oder?"

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't know if that non-specific advice in ISO/DIN makes life easier as long as supervisors insist what they just conjured up/like is ISO 690. It certainly doesn't help with the Babylonian naming problem of everybody calling their style DIN/ISO-whathaveyou.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is the case. Every supervisor can define his/her own style and force a student to make it like that. Still, i think a student should ask if a generic biblatex style is close enough, which (i hope) will often enough be the case.

Comment: @moewe Everything works fine, except the option setting `giveninits=true` in the package `biblatex`, when I run the code with `giveninits=true`, error occurs, it said `package keyval error: giveninits undefined`, how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Problem solved: I replace the `giveninits=true` with `firstinits=true`,  and replace `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}` with `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}`, and it works well.

Comment: @WangyanLi Yes my MWE assumes you are running the most recent version of biblatex, with versions < 3.3 you will have to use `firstinits` and `last-first`. Everything else should work fine, though. In a way this is the reverse of [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Comment: one more question: I just found that many title entries in my .bib files are capitalised, which lead a capitalised title output, the desired one is only the first letter of the title is capitalised (as shown in question). How can I come to this by adding one or few commands.

Comment: @WangyanLi Add `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}`. But see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86043/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22980/35864 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20335/35864

Comment: @moewe Since I used to the `natbib` package instead of `biblatex` package, is there a way to adapt it in the `natbib` setting?

Comment: @WangyanLi This answer totally relies on `biblatex`. If you need a `natbib` style (a `.bst` style) you will have to go down a different route altogether. That would certainly warrant a new question. But it is unlikely someone will code the entire `.bst` for you.